# Calling jquery ajax gives me a 405(Method Not Allowed:) error

Tags: jquery, django

I have a question

Calling jquery ajax gives me a 405(Method Not Allowed:) error
The error message doesn't tell me why.
The request itself seems to be the cause of the problem.
if you know what's the problem for this problem
thanks for let me know~!

ajax

```
$('body').on('click', '.skill_search_button', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.history.pushState("", "", '/wm/myshortcut/')
    const search_word = $(".skill_input_box").val();
    console.log("search_word : " + search_word);

    $("input:radio.search").each(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).is(":checked")) {
            search_option = this.id;
        } else {
            // alert("check")
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'search_by_id_and_word/',
        data: {
            'search_word': search_word,
            'search_option': search_option,
            'page_user': "{{page_user}}",
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
            },
        success: function (result) {
            window.history.pushState("", "", '/wm/myshortcut/')
            $("#wm_list_area_for_popup").html("")
            $("#wm_list_area_for_popup").append(result)
        }
    });
});
```

url

```
    path('myshortcut/search_by_id_and_word/' , views.searchSkilNoteViewByIdAndWord.as_view(), name="search_by_id_and_word"),
```

view

```
class searchSkilNoteViewByIdAndWord(ListView):
    model = MyShortCut
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = 'wm/MyShortCut_list_for_search.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        if request.method == "POST" and request.is_ajax():
            search_user_id = request.user
            search_word = request.POST['search_word']
            search_option = request.POST['search_option']
            print("search_user_id : ", search_user_id)
            print("search_word : ", search_word)
            print("search_option : ", search_option)
            user = User.objects.get(username=search_user_id)
            qs = MyShortCut.objects.filter(Q(author = user)).filter(Q(title__icontains=search_word) | Q(content1__icontains=search_word) | Q(content2__icontains=search_word)).order_by('-category')
            return qs
        else:
            qs = MyShortCut.objects.filter(Q(author = user)).filter(Q(title__icontains=search_word) | Q(content1__icontains=search_word) | Q(content2__icontains=search_word)).order_by('-category')
            return qs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At server side you should care about what model would be acceptable,in this case i think models are different or method VERB in both side should be same:

```
client      server
 POST        POST
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your template tag:

from

```py
csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
```

to

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
```

Also include `{% csrf_token %}` in your template

More information on [Cross Site Request Forgery in [Django-Docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/#acquiring-the-token-if-csrf-use-sessions-or-csrf-cookie-httponly-is-true)

Comment: I tried it but it's now work but thnkas for let me know